# How can i backup a folder with files inside but skipping on custom folder?

Tags: ubuntu, server, zip

I have my project that have a lot of files inside system/files directory.
I need to backup the source without the files uploaded, because if ill wait for the files for finish it will take forever..
How can i skip a folder with a custom name that i set.
Thanks you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The example command to exclude directory `directory1` for example will be like (assume you are in the directory from where you want to get files):

```
zip -r /path/to/archive.zip -x 'directory1` *
```